# VTable setup of type Unity.UnityContainer+Context failed

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, unity-container, prism

I have runtime error "VTable setup of type Unity.UnityContainer+ContainerContext failed" in my Xamarin.Forms application after I upgraded some libraries from nuget to the latest version. Running it on Android.

I didn't do any other changes in the code itself. I upgraded to stable versions only.

- Unity - 5.11.1
- Xamarin.Forms - 4.2.0815419
- Prism - 7.2.0.1367

Here is the stack:

at Prism.Unity.PrismApplication.CreateContainerExtension () [0x00000] in d:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin\Prism.Unity.Forms\PrismApplication.cs:44 
  at Prism.PrismApplicationBase.Initialize () [0x00000] in d:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin\Prism.Forms\PrismApplicationBase.cs:130 
  at Prism.PrismApplicationBase.InitializeInternal () [0x00006] in d:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin\Prism.Forms\PrismApplicationBase.cs:84 
  at Prism.PrismApplicationBase..ctor (Prism.IPlatformInitializer platformInitializer, System.Boolean setFormsDependencyResolver) [0x00038] in d:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin\Prism.Forms\PrismApplicationBase.cs:75 
  at Prism.PrismApplicationBase..ctor (Prism.IPlatformInitializer platformInitializer) [0x00000] in d:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin\Prism.Forms\PrismApplicationBase.cs:57 
  at Prism.Unity.PrismApplication..ctor (Prism.IPlatformInitializer platformInitializer) [0x00000] in d:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin\Prism.Unity.Forms\PrismApplication.cs:30 
  at TennisUmpireXamarin.App..ctor (Prism.IPlatformInitializer initializer) [0x00000] in C:\Dev\MaxalLabs\TennisUmpire\src\TennisUmpireXamarin\TennisUmpireXamarin\App.xaml.cs:34 
  at TennisUmpireXamarin.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x0009e] in C:\Dev\MaxalLabs\TennisUmpire\src\TennisUmpireXamarin\TennisUmpireXamarin.Droid\MainActivity.cs:65 
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in <3324153164274220ab14392825330ba2>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.17(intptr,intptr,intptr)

Any help or advice is appreciated. I would prefer to not rollback, but stay on latest versions.

Comment: Removing all object files and rebuilding _might_ help.

Comment: Thank you, after clearing all /obj and /bin folders I actually see compiling errors related to Unity.Abstractions referencing System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions. Now need to track it down. Just adding System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions to didn't help, but it's something.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix it by adding latest version of Unity.Container (5.11.1) directly to my Xamarin Project, which is higher than what Prism.Unit.Forms tried to link.

Comment: OMG ! Thanks for saving my time... I started to get crazy !!! Why Prism.Unity.Forms use Unity.Container 5.10.3 when other dependency target 5.11.1 !!